# I added python to path when installed but recieved warning "Python is not installed"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I already installed Python. I had added it when installed. I had checked it, too.(pic2&3, my python version was 3.10.5150.1013)

Image:

[image]
pic1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xn5I.jpg)
pic2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF3ZQ.jpg)
pic3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ctrl+shift+p` to open the command palette and search for `Python:Select Interpreter` (or click select interpreter in the lower right corner).

[image]

If the panel shows an interpreter, select the available interpreter. If the panel doesn't have an interpreter option. Please select the first item `Enter interpreter path`.

[image]

Then paste the full path to your `python.exe` (or go to explorer by selecting `Find` and select your `python.exe`).

[image]

Comment: I did as told and got other problem. I searched the way to solve those problem and eventually everything worked out it seemed. I hoped it stay this way. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Python is not in %PATH% environment variable, in the Python installation, it asks you if you'd like to add Python in the %PATH% variable, you may have missed it, you can manually add Python executable in the %PATH% variable more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537574(v=office.14)

Comment: @A@ But I had added it when installed. I had checked it, too.(pic2&3, my python version was 3.10.5150.1013)